# How can I modify the settings.xml so if the dependency is not present in local, get it from Internet

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have using maven 3.3 to build project. Here we are using a local maven repository,.
This is the settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>mirrorOfmaven</name>
      <url>http://10.2.2.29:8080/artifactory/mirrorOfmaven</url>
      <id>mirrorOfmaven</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>      
        <repository>
          <id>ext-release-local</id>
          <name>ext-release-local</name>
          <url>http://10.2.2.29:8080/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>   
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>libs-release-local</id>
          <name>libs-release-local</name>
          <url>http://10.2.2.29:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>       
      </repositories>      
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
        <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        <wls.adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</wls.adminurl>
        <wls.username>weblogic</wls.username>
        <wls.password>weblogic</wls.password>
        <wls.targets>artserver</wls.targets>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
        <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
        <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Here now i need to use maven jaxb2 plugin,

```
 <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
```

which is not present in my local repository.

On run it gives error,

```
Failure to find org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:jar:0.13.3 in http://10.2.2.29:8080/artifactory/mirrorOfmaven was cached in the local repository
```

How can I modify the settings.xml so if the dependency is not present in local, get it from Internet.

Comment: Please correct me, if I'm wrong. I understand that you're using the Artifactory. Please visit the following link for further configuration the remote repository. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories and https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Artifactory deployed in our intranet, but maven jaxb2 plugin is not present there. It has to be downloaded from internet directly.  How can I do this. Le t me know you need any info ?

Comment: You should configure Artifactory to proxy Central repository....furthermore you should than change the mirrorOf into `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` to redirect everything via your Artifactory...

Comment: Any alternative, If i don't have the permission to modify the Artifactory ?

Comment: Setting up Multiple Repositories may help. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html. We may configure to both maven central and intranet artifactory together.